# Scroll divs inside a div instead of img tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using a JQuery scroll plug in which scrolls images in a div, sort of like a marquee.
I am trying to achieve the same thing, however instead of img tags I would like to scroll div tags.

[Scroller](http://kiusso.net/scripts/imageScroller_jquery_plugin/)

At present this is the mark-up

```
       <div id="contentscroller" style="clear:both;">
            <div id='left' class="logo-carousel">
                <div class="logo-test"></div>
                <img src='/images/lve.png' />
                <img src='/images/friendslife.png' />
                <img src='/images/aviva.png' />
                <img src='/images/bright-grey.png'/>
                <img src='/images/sagicor.png'/>
                <img src='/images/zurich.png'/>
                <img src='/images/legal-general.png'/>
                <img src='/images/groupama.png'/>
                <img src='/images/fortress.png'/>      
             </div>
        </div>
```

This is the JS

```
<script>
$(
function () {
    $("#left").imageScroller({ loading: 'Wait please...' });
    $("#right").imageScroller({ speed: '4000', direction: 'right' });
    $("#top").imageScroller({ direction: 'top' });
    $("#bottom").imageScroller({ speed: '3500', direction: 'bottom' });
}
)
</script>
```

I need to achieve the same thing, however simply using div elements with a background image. The result will be exactly the same however instead of images, I would use empty divs with the image as the background, to avoid HTTP requests and to speed up the site performance.

I have tried replacing the images with divs, however it doesn't work because the JS is specificly targeting img tags inside the contentscroller div.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the original library is not the best answer, but it's what I want to suggest because the library simply looks for images and NOT divs. Take a look at some of its [source](http://kiusso.net/scripts/imageScroller_jquery_plugin/js/jquery.imageScroller.js):

```
$.each($this.children( ":not(div)" ), function() ...
```

This is simple, the library isn't looking for divs... What's the work around going to be? Create your own library based on their ideas.

Comment: what would I change it to? Where and how many changes would I need to make?